# Firefox doesn't show pictures with square brackets in filename

Tags: html, firefox, grails

I have a problem with Firefox browser and picture rendering in Grails web application.
Some of the pictures have "[" and "]" in filename. When I open web application in Chrome or Explorer, pictures are ok but not in Firefox.

My code looks like this:

GSP:

```
<img
    src="${resource(dir:'documents/pictures',file:filename)}" alt="" />
```

Filename has square brackets.

I know that Firefox has problems with square brackets but is there a workaround?
Thank you.

Generated html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 product-image">
    <div id="slikaTemp">
        <br>
        <a href="/application/static/documents/pictures/TETRIC_EVOCERAM__4ddb881283a15[1].jpg" title="">
            <img src="/application/static/documents/pictures/TETRIC_EVOCERAM__4ddb881283a15[1].jpg" alt="" height="" width="450">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show us the generated html

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the filename so in your resource call, add something with  `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(filename)` so the filename will be encoded